# Sql NOT IN optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm having trouble optimizing a query. Here are two example tables I am working with:

```
Table 1:
UID
A
B

Table 2:
UID   Parent
A       2
B       2
C       3
D       2
E       3
F       2
```

Here is what I am doing now:

```
Select Table1.UID
FROM Table1 R

INNER JOIN Table2 T ON
R.UID = T.UID

INNER JOIN Table2 E ON
T.PARENT = E.PARENT
AND E.UID NOT IN (SELECT UID FROM Table1)
```

I'm trying to avoid using the NOT IN clause because of obvious hindrances in performance for large numbers of records.

I know the typical ways to avoid NOT IN clauses like the LEFT JOIN where the other table is null, but can't seem to get what I want with all of the other Joins going on.

I will continue working and post if I find a solution.

EDIT: Here is what I am trying to end up with

After the first Inner Join I would have

```
A
B
```

AFter the second Inner join I would have:

```
A    D 
A    F
B    D
B    F
```

The second column above is just to represent that it is matching to the other UIDs with the same parent, but I still need the As and Bs as the UID.

EDIT: RDBMS is SQL server 2005, 2008r2, 2012

Table1 is declared in the query with no index

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE ( [UNIQUE_ID] INT PRIMARY KEY )
```

Table2 has a clustered index on Unique ID

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: NOT IN *can* be rewritten as a LEFT OUTER with NULL check. Whether or not it makes a difference depends upon how the Query Planner treats the two queries - so show a plan. (I almost always take the joins, out of preference for how it exposes the RA.)

Comment: Which RDBMS? `NOT IN` behaves quite well in most DBMS, with proper indexes.

Comment: Down voted the question because I believe its founded on a misunderstanding -- as others comment, NOT IN is not necessarily a performance problem. NOT IN is amenable to rewrite to an anti-join, making it potentially more efficient than an outer join especially if the optimiser doesn't recognise that the outer join should be transformed to an anti-join.

Comment: The NOT IN was causing my query to take over an hour for 2 million records. I changed it to a left outer join (granted it caused my query to be a little off) and it reduced it to 5 minutes.

Comment: `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT UID FROM Table1 WHERE UID = E.UID)`, with an index on `UID` on `Table1`?

Comment: How sure are you that it was `NOT IN` to blame and not lack of indexes that could be used?

Comment: If you want the query optimized (as your tag implies), include (at least) the DBMS you are using, the tables' definitions (CREATE statements), the indexes on them and the execution plan the query gives.

Comment: NOT IN (SELECT X FROM Table) performs bad only when X is nullable.

Comment: Are you trying to do a recursion through a temp table here?

Comment: For all of the items in Table2 with the same Parent (but not included in Table1), I want a row with  each of the UIDs from Table1

Comment: I would try adding an index on `(parent, UID)`. Also (again): post the execution plans (before and after adding this index.)

Comment: I added a nonclustered index on Table1 and the speed seems to be about where I want it. Does it make sense for that to allow the NOT IN to run efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

The general approach to this is to use a `LEFT JOIN` with a where clause that only selects the *non-matching* rows:

```
Select Table1.UID
FROM Table1 R    
JOIN Table2 T ON R.UID = T.UID
JOIN Table2 E ON T.PARENT = E.PARENT
LEFT JOIN Table3 E2 ON E.UID = R.UID
WHERE E2.UID IS NULL
```

Comment: This is close. I end up with an extra row for each UID from table1, but it is closer than my other implementations. I'll work with it a little and post the final query when I'm done. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Changing them to JOINS didn't change the result set

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Table2.*
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM Table2
  EXCEPT
  SELECT id FROM Table1
) AS Filter ON (Table2.id = Filter.id)
```

Comment: Probably less performing than NOT IN on most query optimisers.

Comment: Not all rdbms's support this syntax.  Also, in some cases, you have to use the word minus instead of except.

Comment: Where 'some cases' = 'Oracle'.