# Converting a working SQL NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some SQL to tell me the superheroes who don't ever wield a sword.

## Creating the table

First, here is the (MySQL) script to create and populate the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`weaponry` (
  `hero` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `weapon` VARCHAR(20) NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB

insert into weaponry (hero, weapon) values ('Wonder Woman', 'Lasso of truth');
insert into weaponry (hero, weapon) values ('Wonder Woman', 'Sword');
insert into weaponry (hero, weapon) values ('Wonder Woman', 'Shield');
insert into weaponry (hero, weapon) values ('Spider Man', 'Web');
insert into weaponry (hero, weapon) values ('Gamora', 'Sword');
insert into weaponry (hero, weapon) values ('Gamora', 'Daggar');
insert into weaponry (hero, weapon) values ('Batman', 'Batarang');
insert into weaponry (hero, weapon) values ('Batman', 'Batgrapple');
insert into weaponry (hero, weapon) values ('Batman', 'Tranquilizer gun');
```

## Working code using a `NOT IN` and a subselect

```
select distinct hero from weaponry
  where hero not in
  (select hero from weaponry where weapon = 'Sword')
```

This correctly returns Spider Man and Batman, who don't wield a sword.

## Alternative 1: Using NOT EXISTS

I would like to implement the same query using `NOT EXISTS`. 
I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231731/509840. 
I tried this:

```
select distinct hero from weaponry
  where not exists
  (select * from weaponry where weapon = 'Sword')
```

Unfortunately, this returns no rows.

## Alternative 2: Using LEFT JOIN

I also took a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17413996/509840 .
I was curious to try replacing the `NOT IN` with a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
  select * from weaponry a
    left join weaponry b on a.hero=b.hero and a.weapon=b.weapon
    where a.weapon <> 'Sword'
```

But this just returns all non-sword heroes (including Wonder Woman and Gamora), since all wield weapons other than swords.

Would you please help me rewrite the NOT IN query with either the `NOT EXISTS` or the `LEFT JOIN`?

### EDIT: Left Join and the correlated subquery

@JeffUK suggested in his comments that one could understand the correlated subquery better by removing the `WHERE` clause. Here's a small modification to the `select` with the `where` removed.

```
select distinct a.hero, weaponryInner.hero from weaponry a
    left join 
        (Select * from weaponry b where weapon = 'Sword') as weaponryInner
    on a.hero=weaponryInner.hero
```

The results are two columns of heroes, some of which are `NULL`.

```
-------------------------------
Hero          |  Hero
-------------------------------
Wonder Woman  |  Wonder Woman
Gamora        |  Gamora
Spider Man    |  <null> 
Batman        |  <null>
-------------------------------
```

So adding the final `where weaponryInner.Weapon is null` will return just Spider Man and Batman.

Comment: Can I just say this is the best formatted question I've seen on here for a long time.  You sir, are a superhero who never wields a sword!

Comment: Agreed sample data, what has been tried, expected results... what more could a person trying to help ask for.  Keep up the good work @rajah9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First one you are checking for the existence of any sword wielding heros, you need to check only for the 'current' hero wielding a sword.

```
select distinct hero from weaponry as a
  where not exists
  (select * from weaponry as b where b.weapon = 'Sword' and b.hero = a.hero )
```

The second won't work for you, a join works on each row independently, so will do exactly what you're seeing. You could do something like this, a bit more complex but does the job.

We find only the heros with swords in the subquery, and join that to all heros,  any heros with a 'NULL' weren't found in the subquery, therefore never wield swords.

```
select distinct a.hero from weaponry a
    left join 
        (Select * from weaponry b where weapon = 'Sword') as weaponryInner
    on a.hero=weaponryInner.hero 
where weaponryInner.Weapon is null
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain the correlated subquery concept and how it works. and for the left; ahh the good ole absense of data is data.. though not sure why you need the full outer.

Comment: Expanded on it a little. The best way to understand what's happening would be to remove the final 'Where' clause, and change it to Select * on the first line. Then run it and review the results

Comment: thank you, both of your alternatives work. To @xQbert's question, I'll make an edit to my post. (Too messy to do inline.)

Comment: Query cost for the NOT EXISTS: 2.80. Query cost for the LEFT JOIN: 7.20.

Comment: Ultimately the left join is, in a round about way, doing a 'not exists'  so no surprise it's less efficient than a built-in function to do the same job.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the below:

```
select distinct hero from weaponry w
LEFT JOIN
(select hero from weaponry where weapon = 'Sword') h ON h.hero = w.hero
WHERE h.hero IS NULL
```

Comment: I made a slight change to the query ("distinct hero" --> "distinct w.hero") and your left join correctly replicated the original NOT IN results. Well done.

Comment: Query cost from SQL explain: 7.20.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT h.hero
  FROM weaponry h
    LEFT JOIN weaponry w
      ON    w.hero = h.hero
        AND w.weapon = 'Sword'
  WHERE w.weapon is null
  GROUP BY h.hero
```

OR

```
SELECT distinct h.hero
  FROM weaponry h
  WHERE not exists( SELECT 1 
                      FROM weaponry w
                      WHERE w.hero = h.hero
                        AND w.weapon = 'Sword'
                  )
```

Comment: Thank you, both answers work. I have tweaked the LEFT JOIN answer a bit and found that you can use a SELECT DISTINCT and drop the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Query cost for the LEFT JOIN: 16.20 (as written). Query cost for the LEFT JOIN using a DISTINCT and dropping the group by: 7.20. Query cost for the NOT EXISTS: 2.80.

Comment: Do you have an index on weaponry.hero? or even better on hero and weapon?.

Comment: No, not using indexes on this small example DB. But interesting speedup when the GROUP BY is dropped and a DISTINCT is added. And NOT EXISTS rocks and will become my new favorite.